# How to get full file path using input type = file in Angular in browsers other than IE

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to get full file path on uploading the file in Angular, is there any way i can get it. Please let me know. thanks

Comment: First of all the file selected in input it is come from temp location you get that.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the exact path of your file instead of a fakepath ? Because this is not possible. Your browser prevent this unsafe situation by bypassing the path.

Comment: **For jQuery**
Follow this post
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: This will get you the temp path

Comment: Security prevents it.

Comment: I want to upload a file, before uploading i need to know the file path, so.. when I select any preferred folder in browse option, it should give me the file path